# Import of python-levenshtein/levenshtein failed after successfully pip install

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

after successfully `pip install python-Levenshtein` I can't import this lib. I tried several import commands, but I'll always get the same error message in VS Code `Import "Levenshtein" could not be resolved, Pylance(reportMissingImports)`:

```
from Levenshtein import distance as lev
import Levenshtein as lev
import Levenshtein
import python_levenhstein
```

If I list up my packages `pip list`,  I get all my packages inside my venv:

```
Package            Version
------------------ -------
jarowinkler        1.0.2
Levenshtein        0.18.1
pip                22.0.4
python-Levenshtein 0.12.2
rapidfuzz          2.0.11
setuptools         60.10.0
```

I created a virtual env via terminal with `python3 -m venv .venv` and activate it by `source .venv/bin/activate`.

Also, when I go to my .venv  I see this levenshtein package folder.
It's my first time using VS Code, so it might be a settings failure, but I tried installing other packages into my venv, and I was able to import them.

Comment: most likely your VS project uses the default system interpreter and not your venv. I have no experience with VS code, but i hope [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) gets you started

Comment: @mnikley Oh thank you for this hint. It was not the right interpreter selected. So this question can be closed.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is thatLevenshtein uses C code. Try adding wheels for it --> https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein-wheels/#files.

Comment: `pip` already downloads wheels by default, so this answer is incorrect.